# How to find out if somebody is spying on my private browsing data in the same WiFi network?

Tags: network, privacy, wifi, safe-browsing-filter

I live in a hostel and eight people including me, are using the same WiFi network. One of my friends is a "computer wizard".

I would like to know if he is secretly checking my browsing history and if he is able to see the websites that I visited in the incognito mode.

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is no defense against wizardry.

Comment: but how can i know whether he is doing so or not???

Comment: There is no way for you or anyone else to know for sure. We can only make assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually visiting your browser history is not possible as long as he doesn't have acces to your computer. *Assuming your computer is not infected by him and he doesn't have physical access to your computer.* Although inspecting, monitoring or saving the network traffic is possible.

What you can do is. Just ask him from man-to-man. Secondly you can use a Virtual Private Network like https://ipredator.se and always make sure you use SSL (HTTPS) as much as possible.

> A browser plugin like [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/HTTPS-EVERYWHERE) can also help you with that. Like @Aron Foster suggested.

If you are a more advanced user you can also decide to scope the networks by setting up different VLAN's. Just remember he will probably find a way around that.

Some basic rules also apply:

1. Keep your operating system and all the used software always up-to-date to prevent possible exploiting and infecting your machine. Like Windows update and also [Filehippo update checker](http://filehippo.com/download_app_manager) can be helpful.
2. Make use of a virus scanner, firewall and anti-malware software. Like [Avira](http://www.avira.com/en/avira-free-antivirus), [Comodo](https://personalfirewall.comodo.com/) and [Spybot search and destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/mirrors/).
3. Use strong and different passwords for different websites. You might want to use a password manager like [KeePass](http://keepass.info/).

> Instead of a VPN service you can also use a free option like [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) like @Neil Smithline suggested. Personally I noticed that using [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/) could slowdown your internet speed drastically. It could be worth to try it out.

Answer (score 5):

Incognito mode does not provide any protection from Wi-Fi snooping; it merely stops your browser from saving your browsing history locally. If you're using unsecured Wi-Fi (or secured Wi-Fi where the attacker knows the password), there is no way to detect if your friend has been recording your web traffic. Any http sites you visited have potential to have been snooped. If your friend was snooping, he or she may be able to determine which https sites you've visited, but wouldn't be able to determine what you did on them beyond how long you spent on the site and how much data you exchanged.

If you're concerned, you need to talk to your friend. You should also look into enabling WPA2 on the shared router (even if everyone knows the password, it makes it harder for the attacker) and using something like [HTTPS everywhere](https://www.eff.org/HTTPS-EVERYWHERE) to avoid using http versions of sites when you can. If you're even more concerned about your privacy, @dwarf015 had a good idea: buy vpn service and connect to that.

Comment: when i looked into my wifi connection properties, the security is set as WPA Personal. does that have any implications?

Comment: If you're using WPA then your friend would have a harder time monitoring your browsing. However, [it's still possible](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11).

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends. If your friend is using Wireshark or similar software that allows capture the packets, then yes he will be able to intercepts the HTTP traffic in WiFi network.

So put it simple:

If you and your friends are browsing HTTP web pages, then "computer wizard" will be able to see what you and your friends are doing.

Answer (score 2):

If he knows the admin password to the WiFi router or network switch he can monitor every URL that you access. Many routers even come with monitoring facilities built into them to support monitoring of one's kids' internet activities. Using SSL prevents your friend form knowing the contents of what is transmitted over the pages but the sites you access are still available.

There are two options that i can think of.

The solution I use is VPN. I use [Private Internet Access](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/) and am very happy with them. They cost $40/year. That's pretty cheap but may be out of your price range. There are free VPN providers but I have no personal information about them and wonder if they are too good to be true.

The free option that I'm familiar with is [TOR](https://www.torproject.org/). It secures all of your browser traffic. I think there's some extra configuration to do for streaming videos but I found a [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQJXT87SWz4) with instructions.

Unless your friend has access to your computer, I'm confident that either VPN or TOR will provide you with the anonymity you want. Both of these options will provide you privacy even if your friend has admin access to the router.